# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{in\theta}$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

For my homework class, we need to prove that a certain series converges, for which it is useful to use that this series is bounded ($\theta \in (0,2\pi)$):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{in\theta}$$

I think that for all $m$

$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{m}e^{in\theta}\right|\leq \frac{2}{\theta}+1$$

But I do not see how I can prove this.

*edit for removing the max function, increasing simplicity*

Comment: Hint: recall the partial sum formula for a geometric series

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me!

Comment: Great! If you can take it from there, then feel free to write an answer yourself and accept it. That way we can go ahead and close this question.

Comment: @DavidH You mean declare this question answered, not close it.

Comment: Your proposed upper bound of $2/\theta + 1$ is false for $\theta$ close to $2\pi$, say $5 \le \theta < 2\pi$.

Comment: Erick Wong you are right, after working it out I got the right bound. Should I still change the question or is that unnecessary?

Comment: The infinite series *doesn't* converge. So you can't say it's bounded, because it doesn't exist. What you're saying is that the partial sums are bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on DavidH's hint.
Since $\theta \ne 0, 2\pi$, $e^{i\theta} \ne 1$.  Therefore we use the geometric series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N e^{in\theta} = \frac{1 - e^{i(N+1)\theta}}{1 - e^{i\theta}}
$$
So
$$
\left| \sum_{n=0}^N e^{in\theta} \right|
= \left| \frac{1 - e^{i(N+1)\theta}}{1 - e^{i\theta}} \right|
\le \frac{2}{|1 - e^{i \theta}|}\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: It isn't true that $|1-e^{ix}| \le 1$.

Comment: How did you get the very last inequality??

Comment: @Braindead, **now** it does. If you check when I wrote the comment and before **your** editing, it didn't...

Comment: And still, @Goos: how from your work does the given bound follow?

Comment: @DonAntonio This is not a proof of the OP's claimed bound, which is probably false.  This is a proof that the partial sums are bounded.  And sorry for the mistake(s) earlier.