# Show that the complex series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i n/3}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I was thinking and revisiting a problem that I had to solve last year in an Introductory Complex Analysis exam. It went like this: Present an example of a convergent series of complex numbers $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n^3$ diverges.

My solution was to make use of the cube root of unity, by defining $\large z_n=\frac{e^{2\pi i n/3}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$. In this fashion, one can easily see that $\large z_n^3=\frac{e^{2\pi i n}}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$, and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n^3$ diverges by the harmonic series. However, I was not able to prove that the series of $z_n$ was convergent. I am somewhat positive that the series is indeed convergent, as WolframAlpha computes that it converges to $\text{Li}_{1/3}(e^{2\pi i/3})$. It's quite obvious that the convergence won't be absolute, as $|z_n|=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ gives a divergent series. I attempted to separate $z_n=a_n+b_n i$ for $a_n=\cos(2\pi n/3)/\sqrt[3]{n}$ and $b_n=\sin(2\pi n/3)/\sqrt[3]{n}$, but I couldn't get this to be very fruitful. Any ideas?

Note: I also know that there are sequences $z_n$ that satisfy this property and are such that $\mathfrak{Im}(z_n)=0$, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I feel like you should be able to sum the terms in groups of three.  What does $1/\sqrt[3]{n} + e^{2\pi i / 3} / \sqrt[3]{n+1} + e^{4\pi i / 3} / \sqrt[3]{n+2}$ look like for large $n$?  It should go to zero much faster than $n^{-1/3}$, since the terms almost cancel each other out.

Comment: @EricSnyder Oh yes, I had a typo in the title (although with a change in the $z_n$ it would make sense either way). I can see that the sum of three consecutive terms should "almost cancel out" as mjqxxxx mentioned, due to it almost having a factor of $\omega^2+\omega+1$, but even if in the limit this goes to zero, it doesn't really say much about the convergence of the series. At least not immediately.

Comment: Would a geometric proof work? As the denominator decrease with each step, the length of the summand vectors decreases. Since the summand vector *directions* are aligned with the edges of an equilateral triangle, and each new leg is smaller than the last, the sum must be constrained by the triangle $[0,1,1/2 + i\sqrt3/2]$. It's a triangular spiral, spiralling inward forever. Then, since when $n$ is large, the sun of each triplet of consecutive terms tends to zero, the sum has to converge on one point in those bounds.

Comment: Ack, wait. Rotate those bounds $120°$ clockwise, since the first term is in the direction of the first root. So $[0,-1,-1/2+i\sqrt3/2]$.

Comment: Hint: with $\omega:=e^{2i\pi/3}$, rewrite your series as $\frac{\omega}{\Gamma(1/3)}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-2/3}}{e^x-\omega}dx$ (why is the $\int$/$\sum$ exchange justified?) What are the integrand's asymptotic behaviours for small/large $x$?

Comment: Can't you just use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)   with $\ b_n =e^{2\pi i n/3}\ $ and $\ a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\ ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Well, I suppose that's a lot simpler than what I wrote, but it's so *dry*, don't you think?

Comment: Not sure why you say that summing three terms at a time doesn't say much about the convergence.  If the series with terms $a_{3k}+a_{3k+1}+a_{3k+2}$ is summable, and the individual terms $a_n$ go to zero (which they do), then the original series is also summable (and sums to the same value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convergence of the series can be proven as follows: first of all you have the characterisation: a complex series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n$, with $z_n=x_n+i y_n$ converges to $z_*=x_*+iy_*$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=x_*$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n=y_*$. This allows you to solve the problem if you are able to show that the  series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(2\pi n/3) n^{-1/3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(2\pi n/3)n^{-1/3}$ converge. Both series are convergent by the Dirichlet's test. For example regarding the first series you have $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)\right| = \left|\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(N+1)}{3}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)}{1 - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)}\right| \leq \frac{1}{\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right|} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: This seems to be it! I didn't know about Dirichlet's test, but it seems to do the job right. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You don't even need to split it up into $\cos$ and $\sin,$ for example see the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770195/prove-that-sum-n-0-inftyein-theta-is-bounded

Comment: Yes, @AdamRubinson is right

Answer (score 2):

To try to formalize the geometric proof:

Let $a_n=1/\sqrt[3]{n}$. Now we can examine any consecutive triplet of terms as:

$$a_k \omega + a_{k+1} \omega^2 + a_{k+2}$$

with $k \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Note that $a_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence.

Each term or triplet is a vector in $\mathbb{C}$, and the vectors are parallel to the sides of an equilateral triangle in quadrant IV with its base along the negative real axis. If we set the vectors tip-to-tail, the vertices of the spiral that will form are the partial sums of the series.

Our first three vectors have lengths of $1, a_2, a_3$, all less than or equal to $1$. These three vectors, tip to tail, will give us a partial sum somewhere in the triangle with vertices at the complex coordinates $\omega, -1, 0$. The partial sum  $S_3$ will quite plainly be in quadrant IV, and because $a_3 < a_2<a_1=1$, it will be left of the first vector. Our fourth vector will be parallel to but shorter than the first three vectors, and hence cannot cross the path of the second vector. For the same reason, the fifth vector cannot cross the third, ad infinitum.

This is sufficient to show the sum is bounded, as it cannot escape this triangle, but not sufficient to establish convergence; for that, we consider what happens as $n$ gets large. Because the sequence is strictly decreasing, and in the infinite limit $\sqrt[3]{k} \sim \sqrt[3]{k+1} \sim \sqrt[3]{k+2}$, we have:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k \omega + a_{k+1} \omega^2 + a_{k+2} = 0$$

Thus, the boundary of the spiral shrinks forever. While convergence is not absolute, the partial sum has a smaller and smaller orbit as $n$ increases, because the sums of triplets tend toward $0$.

---

This isn't perfectly formal as it's late, but I think the argument works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I like the geometric intuition very much, although in this case I feel like an analytic solution does the job a little easier.

Comment: @MathEnjoyer I think this is one of those cases where a "proof without words" might be better than what I wrote. The obvious infinite triangular spiral is neat to visualize but would look better actually drawn out. :)